# Visual Studio Dynamic Compilation working for .aspx but not for .ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dynamic-compilation

After migrating a website project I am facing a strange behaviour of Visual Studio Dynamic compilation. Whenever I modify an aspx file or master page and save it, the modification is visible instantly in my debug browser, I just need to refresh the page. However when I make a modification on an ascx file and save it: no change is visible when I refresh the browser. The modification is only visible if I restart IIS or recompile the whole project.

Does anyone have an idea on whatever might be causing the dynamic compilation not to work properly with ascx when it works fine with aspx and master pages?

Comment: When you modify the aspx page, you are modifying the mark up...right?  But when you modify the ascx...aren't you modifying the code?

Comment: the modifications I am talking about concern the code for aspx.cs and ascx.cs as well. Before migrating this project, dynamic compilation was working fine for ascx.cs but not any longer. I still can't figure out what has happened.